# PHP: how to access methods from associated classes

Tags: php

I have a class, who has a property that is a second class, who also has a property that is a third class:

```
$classOne = new ClassOne;
$classOne->classTwo = new ClassTwo;
$classOne->classTwo->classThree = new ClassThree;
```

And, consequently, I can do this:

```
$classOne->classTwo->classThree->someClassThreeMethod();
```

And what I'm trying to do is:

```
classThree {
    someClassThreeMethod() {
        $classOne->someMethod();
        // some more code
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to do so, PHP tells me `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function someMethod() on null in...`
So, I tried setting `global $classOne` (inside `someClassThreeMethod`), and since it didn't work, also tried `$classOne` into `$GLOBALS` (didn't work either - on the global scope, outside ClassThree implementation).

So, finally, how do I access `someMethod` from within an associated class?

**UPDATE**
I got a better idea on how to proceed with the answers given so far, so I'm reformulating to a slightly different question: how do I set `$classOne` to be accessible from within `someClassThreeMethod`?

Comment: Make sure you have an object of the class containing that method in your calling class and make sure *that* object calls that method. Or use inheritance. But you just can't share methods like the way you are trying here.

Comment: couldent you just extend? http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: @nogad From what I'm doing, inheritance doesn't apply here; but thank you anyways!

Comment: @JohnConde I'm going to try something like that; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is pass the containing object as an argument when creating the new class.

```
class classTwo {
    private $classOne;

    public function __construct($classOne) {
        $this->classOne = $classOne;
    }

    public someClassTwoMethod() {
        $this->classOne->someMethod();
    }
}
```

Then you would do:

```
$classOne = new ClassOne;
$classOne->classTwo = new classTwo($classOne);
```